# Import opevCV libraries to other projects

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to use canny edge detector from openCV library in another project. How can I resolve the issue "The import org.opencv cannot be resolved"?. I have already imported the openCV library into the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jar you imported to the build path.

Right click on the jar file in your workspace to find the menu entry to do so.